# ERROR with regexp while detecting the link

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, protocols

i am using xampp for testing my website and a regular expression to detect links and convert them to a clickable format but when the user enters www.google.com instead of https://www.google.com the link redirects to localhost/www.google.com

my code

```
function link_detect($text){

  $ex = "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/i";
  return preg_replace($ex,'<a class="click_link" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just because you do not provide `http://`.

Try this

```
function link_detect($text){

  $ex = "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/i";
  return preg_replace($ex,'<a class="click_link" href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

Alternative:

```
function text_to_link($str = NULL)
{
    if($str == '' OR !preg_match('/(http|www\.|@)/i', $str))
    {
        return $str;
    }
 
    $lines      = explode("\n", $str); 
    $return     = '';
    while (list($k,$l) = each($lines)) { 
        $l = preg_replace("/([ \t]|^)www\./i", "\\1http://www.", $l);
        $l = preg_replace("/([ \t]|^)ftp\./i", "\\1ftp://ftp.", $l);
        $l = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^ )!]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $l);
        $l = preg_replace("/(https:\/\/[^ )!]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $l);
        $l = preg_replace("/(ftp:\/\/[^ )!]+)/i", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $l);
        $l = preg_replace("/([-a-z0-9_]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+))/i", "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\">\\1</a>", $l);
        $return .= $l."\n";
    }
 
    return $return;
}
 
 
/*
*
* ------------------------------------------
* Link
* <a href="http://www.yours.com">http://www.yours.com</a>
* <a href="https://www.yours_with_ssl.com">https://www.yours_with_ssl.com</a>
* ------------------------------------------
*
*/
text_to_link('http://yours.com');
text_to_link('https://yours_with_ssl.com');
 
 
/*
*
* ------------------------------------------
* FTP
* <a href="ftp://username:password@yours.com">ftp://username:password@yours.com</a>
* ------------------------------------------
*
*/
text_to_link('ftp://username:password@yours.com');
 
/*
*
* ------------------------------------------
* Email
* <a href="mailto:w.kristories@gmail.com">mailto:w.kristories@gmail.com</a>
* ------------------------------------------
*
*/
text_to_link('w.kristories@gmail.com');
```

---

#### UPDATE

Comment from @Mr.coder

> but if a link allready has a `http://` protocol attached to it then what the `href` would be like `http://http://www.google.com`

Ya, update my answer for `link_detect()`.

```
function link_detect($text)
{
  // $ex = "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/i";
  // return preg_replace($ex,'<a class="click_link" href="http://$1" 
  $ex = preg_replace("/([ \t]|^)www\./i", "\\1http://www.", $text); // Replace www to http://www
  $ex = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/[^ )!]+)/i", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>", $ex);
  return $ex;
}

echo link_detect('www.google.com') . "\n";
echo link_detect('http://google.com') . "\n";
echo link_detect('http://www.google.com') . "\n";
```

Comment: Translation: your regex isn't doing this.  Any link in any HTML page without `http://` in front of it will go to local host (or directory).  Example: `<html><body><a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a></body></html>`

Comment: but if a link allready has a `http://` protocol attached to it then what the href would be like `http://http://www.google.com`

Comment: where is it adressed in your snippet or mine

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this less about your regex and more about your link.

In anchors, the only way for the browser to know that links refer to a site *elsewhere* on the internet is to provide a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier). `http://` denotes a URI (with the scheme `http`).

Remember that on most filesystems a file can have multiple dots, so when you say *go to `www.google.com`* the browser is going to think you mean a file called `www` with the extension `.google.com` is where you want to go. It's no different than `foo.tar.gz`.

If anything, prepend just a `//`, which in browser-terms means *prepend whatever protocol/scheme this page has (`http`/`https`/`file`) to the URL and treat as an external link*.

#### Translating this to Regex

One possible solution is to try to detect `(((https?|file):)?\/\/)?`, extract the 4th group from that (`https?|file`, which will find either `http`, `https`, or `file`), and then prepend it to the beginning of your link, **always** providing `//`.

That way, if no scheme is specified the link will still tell the browser to use a default scheme of whatever the current page is using *and* that the link is *external*.

`((((?:([A-Za-z]{3,9}):)?(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)`

Group `4` now holds the protocol (i.e. `http:`). Prepend whatever is in that to your link with `//` after it (*always*).

Comment: I prefer to think of it as the file `www.google` with the extension `.com`.  But, kudos, actually readable.

Comment: @ebyrob Perhaps :) I know when I script my build systems and need to change extensions I use `indexOf('.')` rather than `lastIndexOf('.')`. It wouldn't make sense to do `.tar.gz` -> `.tar.zip`. Depends on how you view things!

Comment: `.tgz` ftw!  <no further text>